# Record voice from html page and convert it to text using JS?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

this code bellow just can record voice and give u button for download it any help to record voice then convert it to text in frensh thx

```
<script>
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio:true})
        .then(stream => {
            rec = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            rec.ondataavailable = e => {
                audioChunks.push(e.data);
                if (rec.state == "inactive"){
            let blob = new Blob(audioChunks,{type:'audio/x-mpeg-3'});
            recordedAudio.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            recordedAudio.controls=true;
            recordedAudio.autoplay=true;
            audioDownload.href = recordedAudio.src;
            audioDownload.download = 'mp3';
            audioDownload.innerHTML = 'download';
         }
            }
        })
        .catch(e=>console.log(e));

    startRecord.onclick = e => {
      startRecord.disabled = true;
      stopRecord.disabled=false;
      audioChunks = [];
      rec.start();
    }
    stopRecord.onclick = e => {
      startRecord.disabled = false;
      stopRecord.disabled=true;
      rec.stop();
 }
</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @zabop my question that how can i detect voice from micro(like messanger) then write it in webpage ( convert it to String)

Comment: Ok, and what have you tried already? The code above does not seem like working.

Comment: it's javascript function to record voice then u can hear it